# Joomla admin panel

Tags: html, joomla

I need to edit one module, and i have access to admin panel, i've found what "code" (if we could call it that) responsible for this is:

```
{jumi [*3]}
```

Can you please explain me what does this means?

[image]

Comment: Go through this **[link](http://2glux.com/projects/jumi/usage-for-j15)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are Jumi plugin syntax

`{jumi [*3]}`   //includes code stored in the 3 rd record of Jumi component database table

Explanation of syntax

1. There must not be any character between the left bracket { and the keyword jumi in the Jumi syntax.
2. Everything else outside [ ] brackets is stripped out and not processed.
   Jumi interprets the conent of the first bracket as the code source and ties to include it.
3. The code source can be either a file or record in Jumi component database.
4. Beginning from the second bracket [ ] Jumi stores the contents of brackets into $jumi array. The $jumi array (and it values) is accessible from your included php code.